# Getting 400 Bad Request for Feign Client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I have had some trouble while using *open-feign*

I'm using: `Hoxton.RELEASE` with Spring-boot version `2.2.1.RELEASE`

```
Caused by: feign.FeignException: status 400 reading Service#method(List,String); content:
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:62)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:91)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:134)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:301)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:297)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

This error occurs when the list size too big

If the list size is small then the execution succeeds

Thank you ！

Comment: Did you manage to solve this one?

Comment: No, I raised this issue on GitHub and for workaround I was earlier using `@QueryParam` so now shifted that to `@RequestBody`

Comment: @I'm_Pratik were you able to fix this issue?